# Проблема с BearLibTerminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Я хочу написать мини игру в стиле взлома терминала, как в fallout 3\nv.
Я написал что-то типа алгоритма как генерировать строки по типу:

```
0xAD1M  %!$"[$$*&(!%)$&    0x0B0E  INSERT&]$&)&%"]
```

и начал искать как можно передвигать курсор, изменять текст, или цвет текста
на питоне. Наткнулся на библиотеку BearLibTerminal, перенес все на нее.
в итоге получается что то типа такого:

[image: ня]
какая-то каша. Как это можно исправить?

файл miniGame.py:

```
import random
import generator as g;
from bearlibterminal import terminal as t;
t.open();


t.color(t.color_from_name("green"));
t.printf(1,1,"ROBCO INDUSTRIES (TM) TERMALINK PROTOCOL");
t.printf(1,2,"ENTER PASSWORD NOW");
t.printf(1,4,"3 ATTEMPT(S) LEFT: ◻◻◻◻")

for i in range(5,15):
#    t.printf (1,i, str(g.gen16bit(4))+"  "+str(g.genPassline())+"    "+str(g.gen16bit(4))+"  "+str(g.genPassline()));
    t.printf(1,i+1,g.genPreparedLine());
t.refresh();
t.read();

t.close();
```

файл generator.py

```
import random;

passwords = [
    "MYRK",
    "TATA",
    "CHARLEY",
    "STREET",
    "HELLOWORLD",
    "COLORFUL",
    "COLOR",
    "SELECTION",
    "1234",
    "ADMIN",
    "ROOT",
    "LUCKYTHECAT",
    "APELSINKA",
    "KOTOKOPTER",
    "ADMINADMIN",
    "FOOTBALL",
    "GAYPORN",
    "LINUX",
    "TATA07",
    "FUNFACT",
    "INSERT",
    "HAZARD"
]

ansDictonary = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
somecharsDictonary = ['(',')','"', "'",'[',']','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*']
dictonary = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0', 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J', 'K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

def genPassline():
    passw = random.choice(passwords);
    totalChars = 15;
    line = "";
    spawnlimit = 5;
    passwordHaveBeenSpawned = False;
    for i in range(totalChars):
        ans = random.choice(ansDictonary);
        if ans != 1 and totalChars > 0:
            line = line + random.choice(somecharsDictonary);
            totalChars = totalChars - 1;
        elif ans == 1 and passwordHaveBeenSpawned == False and len(line) < spawnlimit:
                line = line + passw;
                totalChars = totalChars - len(passw);
                passwordHaveBeenSpawned = True;
        elif totalChars > 0:
            line = line + random.choice(somecharsDictonary);
            totalChars = totalChars - 1;

    return line;

def gen16bit(length):
    value = "0x";
    for i in range(length):
        value = value + random.choice(dictonary);
    return value;

def genPreparedLine():
    preparedLine = str(gen16bit(4))+"  "+str(genPassline())+"    "+str(gen16bit(4))+"  "+str(genPassline());
    return preparedLine;
```

Comment: Такое ощущение что bearlibterminal сам модифицирует вывод по каким-то спец-символам, которые встречаются в сгенерированных строках. Кст, в питоне точки с запятыми не используются, уберите, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю что `bearlibterminal` сам модифицирует вывод по каким-то спец-символам, которые встречаются в сгенерированных строках.

Добавил вывод в консоль и смотрел что поменялось:

```
for i in range(5, 15):
    line = g.genPreparedLine()
    print(len(line), line)
    t.printf(1,i+1, line)
```

и методом пристального взгляда заметил что на символах `[` и `]` происходит странное, попробовал экранировать их (экранирование через `\` не сработало):

```
somecharsDictonary = ['(',')','"', "'",'[[',']]','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*']
```

И вроде бы работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.**

Автору лучше поразбираться с этим вопросом, а то мало ли еще какие сюрпризы встретятся :)

**PPS.**

Терминал офигенный и задумка интересная, аж ностальгия стала мучить